# How to remove dynamically created div elements in JQuery after deleting a record from db?

Tags: php, jquery

I have created a dynamic Div(s) based on records from database and want to remove any of the specific div and its elements after removal a record from db. I have written  `deleteFile(id)` function where ajax removes the div tag on getting response from php file.

But the specific div is not being removed from front end in my Code. How to properly access the closest div of element. Here is the code. Thank you

```
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table where 
        obj_id=".$idObjDetails;
        $result2= mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
        $count_file_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result2);
        $index=1;
        if($count_file_rows>0)
        {
         while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
        {?>
         <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12 fileDiv">            
            <i class="fa fa-remove float-right" id="e_removeBtn" type="button" onclick=" deleteFile(<?php echo $row2['id'];?>)"></i>
                   <input type="text"  name="e_fileGet" id="e_get_file_<?php echo $index ?>" class="form-control fileClass" readonly value="<?php echo $row2['file_name'];?>"/>    
       </div>
       </div>        
        <?php
         $index++;
        }
     }
    ?>
```

```js
// DELETE Objection -
    function deleteFile(id)
    {
        if(confirm("Are You Sure, You Want to Delete This Objection? "))
        {
            
        var del_file_id=id; 
        var element=this;
       
        $.ajax({
      url:"deleteFile.php",
      type:"POST",
      data: {'id':del_file_id},
      success : function(data){
        ; 
        if(data==1)
        {
            //$("#e_get_file_1").remove();
         $(element).closest(".fileDiv").remove(); 
          //window.location.reload(); 
        }
        else
        {           
          $("#error-message").html("cant del").slideDown();
          $("#Success-message").slideUp();
        }
      }

    });

        }
        //add alert - later 
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to remove the whole element

```
// DELETE Objection -
    function deleteFile(id)
    {
        if(confirm("Are You Sure, You Want to Delete This Objection? "))
        {
            
        var del_file_id=id; 
        var element=this;
        var selector = '#e_get_file_'+id;
       
        $.ajax({
      url:"deleteFile.php",
      type:"POST",
      data: {'id':del_file_id},
      success : function(data){
        ; 
        if(data==1)
        {
            // parent().parent() to reach the .form-row div
            $(selector).parent().parent().remove();
        }
        else
        {           
          $("#error-message").html("cant del").slideDown();
          $("#Success-message").slideUp();
        }
      }

    });

        }
        //add alert - later 
        
    }
```

Comment: id is different then index

Comment: So why don't make them both the same both `id` or both `index`

Comment: to keep different ids to for each dynamically created tag

Comment: isn't the `$row2['id']` unique for each element ?